# UITableViewCell counting from 1 to 50

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm learning Swift 4 with Xcode 9 and tried to make a TableView with 50 cells.
In cell 1 "1"
in cell 2 "2"
and so on.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = String[indexPath.row + 1]
    }
}
```

Now the compiler says on this line `cell.textLabel?.text = String[indexPath.row + 1]`"Instance Member "subscript" can not be used on Type String"

How can I make 50 cells with content 1 to 50?

Comment: `String[indexPath.row + 1]` => `String(indexPath.row + 1)`. Subscripting, that's doing `myObject[something]`, with the square brackets. Dictionary has it, and some other too.

Comment: OMG i used the wrong brackets... thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either or these:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
```

or

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```